# Opening URl using Iframe causing parent page to open with that URI

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to open an `https://xxxxxxx.com` inside an HTML content by using `Iframe`.

```
<body>
    <a href="https://xxxxxxxx.com" target="internal"> Application </a>
    <div>
<iframe name="internal" src="" height="800px" width="1000px" scrolling="auto">
</iframe>
</div>
</body>
```

Problem is: Instead of loading the URL inside the Iframe, parent page itself getting replaced by the URL.(page itself is loaded by this URL)

`Note:` Other URL's like Google are working fine. Only this URL has this issue.

Anyone could suggest.

Comment: The page is probably running a [framebreaker script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller).